# Handlebars conditionals - boolean properties only?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Quick question. Is it possible to evaluate things other than a Boolean property in a handlebars conditional?

eg This works

```
//elsewhere...  myproperty = true
{{#if myproperty}}...
```

Any way other conditionals can be done? eg

```
//elsewhere...  myproperty = 3
{{#if myproperty<4}}...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** do `{{#if myproperty<4}}` in the template.

See the following question for an example of what to do in such a case

[How do I make a conditional helper with ember-cli and handlebars 2.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328412/how-do-i-make-a-conditional-helper-with-ember-cli-and-handlebars-2-0-0/28328818#28328818)

Answer (score 3):

Without a helper, you can't have `if`'s evaluate conditions.  You can, however, make a helper to do it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('iff', function(left, condi, right, options) {
    function ret(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            return options.fn(this);
        } else {
            return options.inverse(this);   
        }
    }

    switch (condi) {
        case "==":
            ret(left == right);
        case "!=":
            ret(left != right);
        case ">":
            //etc, etc, you get the idea
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
{{#iff myproperty "<" 4}}
    Myproperty is less than 4
{{else}}
    Myproperty is greater than or equal to 4
{{/iff}}
```

--edit--

> Haven't tried this yet but it looks sensible and straightforward. Begs
>   the question why Handlebars doesn't support more complex conditionals
>   natively...

It's good practice to separate your logic from your templates (views), because it makes your code more maintainable.  Essentially, it's following the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

Personally, I think having a conditional `if` would be useful as well, because there is definitely a place for one-off `if` statements in templates while keeping your logic and view separate.  However, by not including it by default, it somewhat saves users from themselves, so you don't end up seeing 20+ nested if statements.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but it looks sensible and straightforward. Begs the question why Handlebars doesn't support more complex conditionals natively...

Comment: Right thanks, yeah that makes a lot of sense. Always more to consider!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers)

So in your case you would use `{{if (lt myproperty 4)}}`